# R: sub() using vector as pattern

Tags: r, vector, substitution

Say I have a data frame like the following:

```
df=data.frame(a=LETTERS, b=paste0(LETTERS,1:length(LETTERS)))
```

It looks like this:

```
> df
   a   b
1  A  A1
2  B  B2
3  C  C3
4  D  D4
5  E  E5
6  F  F6
7  G  G7
8  H  H8
9  I  I9
10 J J10
11 K K11
12 L L12
...
```

The only thing I want to do is remove `df$a` from `df$b`, so that the resulting data frame looks like:

```
> df
   a  b
1  A  1
2  B  2
3  C  3
4  D  4
5  E  5
6  F  6
7  G  7
8  H  8
9  I  9
10 J 10
11 K 11
12 L 12
...
```

For that, I want to explicitly use `sub()` with `df$a` as pattern. This data frame is just an example, so I do not want to use `strsplit()` or a specific regex in `sub()` (cause my `df$a` can get pretty complicated).

I try:

```
df$b=sub(paste0("^",df$a) , "", df$b)
```

But obviously I get:

> Warning message: In sub(paste0("^", df$a), "", df$b) :   argument
> 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So what would be the right way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mapply` to remove `df1$a` from `df$b`.

```r
df <- data.frame(a=LETTERS, b=paste0(LETTERS,1:length(LETTERS)))

mapply(\(x, y) sub(x, "", y), df$a, df$b)
#>    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O    P 
#>  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" 
#>    Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z 
#> "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To assign back to `df$b`, keeping as characters, run

```r
df$b <- mapply(\(x, y) sub(x, "", y), df$a, df$b)
head(df)
#>   a b
#> 1 A 1
#> 2 B 2
#> 3 C 3
#> 4 D 4
#> 5 E 5
#> 6 F 6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>